# React Native SWF file

Tags: react-native, flash

Is there a way to read **swf**(action script 3) type file and render it as a flash game in **react-native** like `<embed>` tag in html.

Comment: can https://github.com/sixsided/Simplified-JavaScript-Interpreter work for you ?

Comment: @Wawa No it can't, thanks.
I need to show game with flash in react-native.

Comment: No. Wrong tool to display SWF in a native app. Use Adobe AIR and its ActionScript 3 language to output a native app that supports SWF.